# GOE Version of Longest Increasing Subsequence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, random-matrices, permutations

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group equipped with uniform measure. For any $\pi\in S_n$, let $L_n=L_n(\pi)$ denote the longest increasing subsequence. A celebrated result of Baik, Deift and Johansson states that

$$P\left(\frac{L_n-2\sqrt{n}}{n^{1/6}}\leq s\right)\rightarrow F_2(s),$$

where $F_2(s)$ is the Tracy-Widom distribution, describing the largest eigenvalue of a **GUE** matrix. The connection between longest increasing subsequence, representation theory and random matrix theory is now well established.

> Question: is there another natural statistic on $S_n$ resembling something akin to $L_n$ which follows a **GOE** distribution? Specifically, calling such a statistic $M_n$, I'm interested in a similar result of the form
>
> $$P\left(\frac{M_n-2\sqrt{n}}{n^{1/6}}\leq s\right)\rightarrow F_1(s),$$
> where $F_1(s)$ is now the Tracy Widom distribution of the largest eigenvalue of a **GOE**. Ideally, the scaling $n^{1/6}$ should be the same. I would also prefer to retain uniform measure on $S_n$ but, of course I would be very interested to hear of other examples. As well, the shift can be different as well.

I'm aware of numerous results in combinatorics where $F_1$ comes up in. For example, the fluctations of random aztec diamond tilings follow an Airy process and therefore have GOE behavior. There the scaling is $n^{1/3}$. As well, it comes up in viscous walkers and nonintersecting brownian motion. I mention these examples because there are definitely tangentially linked to $S_n$ through representation theory and growth processes. However, as I said I would ideally like an example of something that naturally occurs on $S_n$.

Answer (score 12):

Involutions $s=s^{-1}$ in $S_n$ are modeled by the Tracy-Widom distribution $F_1$ for real symmetric matrices (GOE):
Take as $S_n^\ast$ the subset of involutions in $S_n$, and let
$M_n$ be the corresponding random variable for the longest increasing subsequence. Then the limit distribution is
$$P\left(\frac{M_n − 2\sqrt n}{n^{1/6}}\leq s\right)\rightarrow F_1(s).$$

J. Baik and E.M. Rains, [Symmetrized random permutations](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910019) (1999).

The same paper also gives a generalization that is modeled by the Tracy-Widom distribution $F_4$ for the GSE (Gaussian symplectic ensemble). For a recent review article, see:

G. Olshanski, [Random permutations and related topics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1266) (2011).